# ¿Cómo evitar que android bloque el segundo plano de una aplicación?

Tags: android, android-studio

He tenido problemas con teléfonos de marca como Huawei Xiomy y Motorola(algunos), como todos sabemos dichos teléfonos usan software que bloquean aplicaciones que utilizan una buena capacidad de batería y más si se ejecutan en segundo plano. 
¿Cómo podría hacer para que mi aplicación android tuviera 100% privilegios y pudiera evitar bloqueos de segundo plano?

Comment: que servicios necesitas?

Comment: GPS y notificaciones

Comment: "bloquean aplicaciones que utilizan una buena capacidad de batería", mejora el procesamiento de batería de tú aplicación y estos no la bloquearán...

Comment: Prueba con  un Service antes que AsyncTask

Comment: Es necesario que la aplicación tenga los permisos para usar la batería,cuando lo vea conveniente, no quiero decir que no sea eficiente al usar la bateria, estoy usando un service antes de la tarea asíncrona, el problema son aquellos dispositivos que ofrecen un software adicional, que bloquea automáticamente las aplicaciones cuando el terminal no se esta usando. ¿Forma de evadirlos?

Comment: @DavidPeña si usas un Service, no debe ser bloqueado por el sistema operativo, no creo sea posible una aplicación pueda bloquear la ejecución de otras aplicaciones, únicamente podría realizarlo el sistema operativo. Cual es la aplicación o aplicaciones de las que comentas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para estas situaciones la mejor alternativa es usar un "Foreground Service", es una configuración especial del servicio que le informa al SO que este servicio corre en primer plano y que debería tener prioridad en el acceso a los recursos. Aquí está [la documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) pero lo que hace falta para ejecutar este servicio es:

1. llamar a `startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);` en el servicio.
2. Esta llamada requiere una notificación, esta notificación se mostrará mientras el servicio se este ejecutando y **no se puede cerrar**.

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a leer la documentación y les cuento mi experiencia

Comment: Una vez que termines te pido que por favor marques la pregunta como respondida. Así ya no aparece en el listado de pendientes.

Comment: La cierro con mi comentario de experiencia.Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el problema a desaparecido con esta linea de código después de la configuración de notification.

```
  startForeground(id, builder.build());
```